# Raspberry Pi spidev automatically in use

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I will use my raspberry pi with a RFID-Reader(RFID-RC522). I wrote a working python program, it's working on my pi3+.
When I start my Pi4, I can't us the programm. So I am looking for spi:

`lsmod | grep spi`

When i start the Pi3+:

```
spidev       20480 0
spi_bcm2835  20480 0
```

On my Pi4 (with same settings) i get:

```
spidev       20480 2
spi_bcm2835  24576 0
```

So there is a channel in use and i have no clue how to find out whats wrong.

I hope you can help me.

Program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import time
CardReader = SimpleMFRC522()
print ('Scanning for a card..')
print ('to cancel press ctrl+c')

try:
     while True:
        id, text = CardReader.read()
        file = open ("../../ftp/files/karte.txt", "w")
        print (id)
        print (text)
        name = repr(text)
        file.write(str(id) + '\n' + text + '\n')
        file.close()
        print ('Successfully read')
        time.sleep(2)

finally:
    gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: Are you sure you've initialized SPI? Here are some decent [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/08/enabling-the-spi-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/). Additionally, your user needs to be a member of the appropriate groups (spi and possibly gpio).

Comment: yes i already did that thats why iam asking. First of all make research and than i ask a stuiped question